# HTML code for validation

Tags: javascript, html

HTML code for validaton of name, mobile number etc by giving error message beside the text box in red colour

```
if(p.length!=10)  region.innerHTML="phone num must be 10 digits";
if(isNaN(p))   region.innerHTML="digits only";
```

I have used this type of format but not working.

Comment: what exactly is not working..the validation or the message showing in red

Comment: Can you replicate your issue in a jsfiddle?

Comment: code for validation by showing error beside the text box

Comment: The way you written the Javascript is Wrong Yaar..then How it will work..So funny :)

Comment: no its work just small changes only

Answer (score 1):

```
if you want to use html validation try this once:

        <style type="text/css">
            .validationError {
                border: solid 2px red;
            }
            .validationValid {
                border:  solid 2px green;
            }
        </style>

    <form id="customerForm">
        <label>
            First Name:
            <input id="firstName" required />
        </label>
        <label>
            Social Security Number:
            <input id="ssn" required pattern="^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$" title="Expected pattern is ###-##-####" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>

script:


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.h5validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Enable h5Validate plugin
    $("#customerForm").h5Validate({
        errorClass: "validationError",
        validClass: "validationValid"
    });

    // Prevent form submission when errors
    $("#customerForm").submit(function (evt) {
        if ($("#customerForm").h5Validate("allValid") === false) {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following function

```
var phoneNumber = "(07) 1234-5678";
phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g,'');
if (phoneNumber.length == 10) {
 region.innerHTML = phoneNumber + ' contains 10 digits';
}
else {
 region.innerHTML= phoneNumber +' does not contain 10 digits';
}
```